# SQL Nested Case in Where Clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sample table with following structure and data.

[image]

I have to select value from this table with respect to the name, type and subtype. If any one of the column value is not matching the condition then value with 'all' should be picked. Below is the query created.
declare name varchar default 'name1'
declare type varchar default 'type1'
declare subtype varchar default 'subtype1'

```
SELECT * FROM sampledata sd 
where
    case when (exists(select 1 from sampledata where name = :name))     
        then sd.name = :name and
        case when exists (select 1 from sampledata where name = :name and type = :type)         
            then sd.type = :type and
                case when exists (select 1 from sampledata where name = :name and type = :type and subtype = :subtype)  
                    then sd.subtype = :subtype 
                    else sd.subtype = 'all' 
                end
            else sd.type = 'all' and    
                case when exists (select 1 from sampledata where name = :name and type = 'all' and subtype = :subtype)  
                    then sd.subtype = :subtype 
                    else sd.subtype = 'all' 
                end
        end             
    else sd.name = 'all' and         
        case when exists (select 1 from sampledata where name = 'all' and type = :type)         
            then sd.type = :type and 
                case when exists (select 1 from sampledata where name = 'all' and type = :type and subtype = :subtype)  
                    then sd.subtype = :subtype 
                    else sd.subtype = 'all'
                end
            else sd.type = 'all' and    
                case when exists (select 1 from sampledata where name = 'all' and type = 'all' and subtype = :subtype)  
                    then sd.subtype = :subtype 
                    else sd.subtype = 'all' 
                end
        end
end
```

This is the result for 'name1', 'type1' and 'subtype1'.

[image]

This is the result for 'name3', 'type3' and 'subtype1' parameters.

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE sampledata (
"name" varchar NULL,
"type" varchar NULL,
subtype varchar NULL,
value float4 NULL
);

INSERT INTO sampledata
("name", "type", subtype, value)
VALUES ('name1', 'type1', 'subtype1', 10),
('name1', 'type2', 'subtype2', 20),
('name1', 'type1', 'all', 30),
('name1', 'type2', 'all', 40),
('name1', 'all', 'subtype1', 50),
('name1', 'all', 'subtype2', 60),
('name1', 'all', 'all', 70),
('all', 'type1', 'subtype1', 80),
('all', 'type2', 'subtype2', 90),
('all', 'all', 'subtype1', 100),
('all', 'all', 'subtype2', 110),
('all', 'all', 'all', 120);
```

The query is working fine and I would like to know if there an optimized logic without using the nested case to achieve the same result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've removed the tag spam. Please only tag the RDBMS you are really using.

Comment: It would help if the example date was available in machine-readable form.

Answer (score 2):

Enumerate and order:

---

```
\i tmp.sql

        -- The table definition
        -- ---------------------------------
CREATE TABLE sampledata
        ( id serial primary key
        , name text
        , type text
        , subtype text
        , val integer
        );

        -- I had to type in the data myself
        -- ---------------------------------
INSERT INTO sampledata ( name , type , subtype ,val)
VALUES ('name1' , 'type1' , 'subtype1', 10)
        , ('name1' , 'type2' , 'subtype2', 20)
        , ('name1' , 'type1' , 'all', 30)
        , ('name1' , 'type2' , 'all', 40)
        , ('name1' , 'all' , 'subtype1', 50)
        , ('name1' , 'all' , 'subtype2', 60)
        , ('name1' , 'all' , 'all', 70)
        , ('all' , 'type1' , 'subtype1', 80)
        , ('all' , 'type2' , 'subtype2', 90)
        , ('all' , 'all' , 'subtype1', 100)
        , ('all' , 'all' , 'subtype2', 110)
        , ('all' , 'all' , 'all', 120)
        ;

SELECT * FROM sampledata ;

        -- Prepared query to allow parameters
        -- ------------------------------------
PREPARE omg(text,text,text) AS
SELECT *
        , 0::int
        + 40*(name = $1)::int
        + 20*(type = $2)::int
        + 10*(subtype = $3)::int
        + 4*(name = 'all' )::int
        + 2*(type = 'all' )::int
        + 1*(subtype = 'all' )::int
        AS flag
FROM sampledata sd
WHERE name in($1, 'all' )
AND type in($2, 'all' )
AND subtype in($3, 'all' )
ORDER BY flag DESC
LIMIT 1
        ;

        -- Example#1
        -- -----------
EXECUTE omg('name1' , 'type1' , 'subtype1' );
        -- Example#2
        -- -----------
EXECUTE omg('name3' , 'type3' , 'subtype1' );
```

---

Results:

---

```
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 12
 id | name  | type  | subtype  | val 
----+-------+-------+----------+-----
  1 | name1 | type1 | subtype1 |  10
  2 | name1 | type2 | subtype2 |  20
  3 | name1 | type1 | all      |  30
  4 | name1 | type2 | all      |  40
  5 | name1 | all   | subtype1 |  50
  6 | name1 | all   | subtype2 |  60
  7 | name1 | all   | all      |  70
  8 | all   | type1 | subtype1 |  80
  9 | all   | type2 | subtype2 |  90
 10 | all   | all   | subtype1 | 100
 11 | all   | all   | subtype2 | 110
 12 | all   | all   | all      | 120
(12 rows)

PREPARE
 id | name  | type  | subtype  | val | flag 
----+-------+-------+----------+-----+------
  1 | name1 | type1 | subtype1 |  10 |   70
(1 row)

 id | name | type | subtype  | val | flag 
----+------+------+----------+-----+------
 10 | all  | all  | subtype1 | 100 |   16
(1 row)
```

Comment: This will return the exact results without random values. Thank you @wildplasser

Comment: If we remove LIMIT 1 the query is returning all entries. Is it possible filter only the matching values (Ex: If "name1" and "type1" matched then only return entries having name = name1 and type = type1, excluding name = all and type = all).

Comment: Yes of course it is. Just observe the resulting `flag` value. You could select on that. (and/or try changing the `weights`)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following approach :

```
WITH list AS
(   SELECT name, type, subtype
         , case when name = 'all' then 2 else 1 end AS name_weight
         , case when type= 'all' then 2 else 1 end AS type_weight
         , case when subtype= 'all' then 2 else 1 end AS subtype_weight
      FROM sampledata sd
     WHERE (name = 'name3' OR name = 'all')
       AND (type = 'type3' OR type = 'all')
       AND (subtype = 'subtype1' OR subtype = 'all')
)
SELECT name, type, subtype
  FROM list
 ORDER BY (name_weight*type_weight*subtype_weight) ASC
 LIMIT 1
```

Then this query will return a random result if both rows exist in the table :

(all, type3,subtype1) and (name3,all,subtype1)

because they will get the same weight = name_weight*type_weight*subtype_weight, so the ORDER BY clause must be refined for this kind of case, for example by defining different weights for name, type, subtype so that to prioritize their importance

Comment: I like this approach. But you are ranking 'all' higher than the direct match. I suppose it shall be the other way round.

Comment: Yes the 'all' is ranked higher than the direct match because the final ORDER BY clause is ASC (ascending order), so that the direct match arrives first and is the only one selected with the LIMIT 1 clause.

Comment: I didn't get the point "Then this query will return a random result if both rows exist in the table : (all, type3,subtype1) and (name3,all,subtype1)". Is this a problem. Sorry for my misunderstanding. Also instead of "ORDER BY (name_weight x type_weight x subtype_weight) ASC" shall we use "ORDER BY name_weight, type_weight, subtype_weight ASC"

Comment: This is very similar to my solution (which **does** handle ties correctly)

Comment: WITH list AS
(
SELECT name, type, subtype, value  
     , case when name = 'all' then 20 else 1 end AS name_weight
     , case when type= 'all' then 10 else 1 end AS type_weight
     , case when subtype= 'all' then 5 else 1 end AS subtype_weight
  FROM sampledata sd
 WHERE (name = 'name1' OR name = 'all')
   AND (type = 'type3' OR type = 'all')
   AND (subtype = 'subtype3' OR subtype = 'all')
)
SELECT name, type, subtype, value
  FROM list
 ORDER BY (name_weight*type_weight*subtype_weight) ASC
LIMIT 1

Updated Query with different weight.